# Why can't my Ansible server not communicate with my Windows XP machine?

Tags: ssh, centos7, windows-xp, ansible

Ansible's official documentation says Windows XP is not a supported os, however, for every day that goes by I'm even more certain you could make it work.

The server is a CentOS 7 machine. I can establish a SSH connection to the Windows XP machine from my server and vice versa.

This is my Ansible hosts file entry for the Windows XP machine:

```
[winxp]
10.0.2.4

[winxp:vars]
ansible_user=nico
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_port=22
```

This is the output when executing `ansible winxp -m win_ping`:

> **10.0.2.4 | UNREACHABLE! => {**
>       **"changed": false,**
>       **"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh:** ----USAGE WARNING---- This is a private computer system. This computer system,
> including all related equipment, networks, and network devices
> (specifically including Internet access) are provided only for
> authorized use. This computer system may be monitored for all lawful
> purposes, including to ensure that its use is authorized,   for
> management of the system, to facilitate protection against
> unauthorized access, and to verify security procedures, survivability,
> and operational security. Monitoring includes active attacks by
> authorized entities to test or verify the security of this system.
> During monitoring, information may be  examined, recorded, copied and
> used for authorizedpurposes. All information, including personal
> information, placed or sent over this system may be monitored. Use of
> this computer system, authorized or unauthorized, constitutes consent
> to monitoring of this system. Unauthorized use may subject you to
> criminal prosecution. Evidence of unauthorized use collected during
> monitoring may be used for administrative, criminal, or other adverse
> action. Use of this system constitutes consent to monitoring for these
> purposes.
>       **Permission denied
> (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).",
> "unreachable": true }**

Why does it say `"Failed to connect to the host via ssh:"` when it can perfectly do so outside of Ansible?

Adding this line to the hosts file doesn't change anything:

```
ansible_ssh_server_cert_validation='ignore'
```

And adding the line `ansible_password=xxxx` and executing the same command shows the following output:

> 10.0.2.4 | UNREACHABLE! => {
>     "changed": false,
>     "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ",
>     "unreachable": true
> }

Does anyone have any idea? Is it really impossible? Do I need a specific python version, powershell version, or anything else installed on the Windows XP machine?

**EDIT: WORKAROUND FOR THIS**
So, as mentioned on the answer, Ansible can't be used on Windows XP. However, there is a workaround for this. You can create a playbook that runs commands on the Windows XP machine using sshpass, and run that playbook on the same Ansible machine. Here is the playbook I used:

```
---
- hosts: ansible_server
  tasks:
    - name: Test
      shell: sshpass -p 'nico' ssh nico@10.0.2.4 "cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\it_works"
```

Hope this can help someone

Answer (score 1):

Even if you manage to get ssh to connect successfully, [Ansible requires PowerShell 3.0](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#host-requirements), which does not work on Windows XP. It needs 2008/Vista or later. You don't need to waste any more time with trying to make it work.